# Setting workDir for gwt codeserver with tbroyer maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I'm using the tbroyer multimodule gwt archetype & 
finding the codeserver compiles take up too much space.
I have a batch file for deleting them but this takes too long so
I'm trying to change the workDir to a ram disk to speed up the deletes (one possible solution).

I tried various things in the parent pom.xml
which is where launcherDir is set using a workDir tag but this didn't change it. Also no success adding -Dgwt.args to the maven goals in my eclipse codeserver debug configuration.

Comment: It takes to much to delete? To compile first time? Or to compile each incremental compilation?

Comment: Anyway, for codeserver and devmode the root project is the right place to configure, see all properties here https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/codeserver-mojo.html, to compile or test you need to configure in the module or in the root if you use the pluginManagement section.

Comment: @Ignacio  thanks I used codeserverWorkDir instead of workDir & it works.

Comment: @Ignacio  The problem I get is that the first compile compile-1 plus all  incremental compiles accumulate. Problem occurs on restarting the codeserver, it hangs  at Super Dev Mode starting up for 5 or 10 minutes if the compile folders are allowed to accumulate

Comment: @timmacp you should put that codeserverWorkDir as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `codeserverWorkDir` property.
https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/codeserver-mojo.html#codeserverWorkDir